# @ in XML tag name

Tags: php, xml

I want to export a database to XML, I use email address as key for the datas:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DS>
    <dsgfsdgfdsgfdg@sg.com>
        <name>remrem</name>
        <email>dsgfsdgfdsgfdg@sg.com</email>
        <datetime>2014-09-23 07:41:57</datetime>
        <lang>fr</lang>
    </dsgfsdgfdsgfdg@sg.com>
    <vcxwv@sdsfg.com>
        <name>remrem</name>
        <email>vcxwv@sdsfg.com</email>
        <datetime>2014-09-23 07:41:57</datetime>
        <lang>fr</lang>
    </vcxwv@sdsfg.com>
</DS>
```

But on read this export, I have always errors because of "@" in the key.
Somebody have a solution for me ?
escaping the "@" ?
use an another key ? (keep email key is better for me)

FYI, I use PHP (SimpleXMLElement)

Thanks !

Comment: why not `<user><name>test</name>...</user>` like this?, by the way, this is not a CSV, its an XML

Comment: Also this is not csv but xml

Comment: Yeah CSV is comma separated values (Can actually be separated by another delimiter if you want). Show your PHP code.

Comment: oO, sorry, need more coffee ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use values in XML tags. The correct way would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DS>
    <userdetails>
        <name>remrem</name>
        <email>dsgfsdgfdsgfdg@sg.com</email>
        <datetime>2014-09-23 07:41:57</datetime>
        <lang>fr</lang>
    </userdetails>
    <userdetails>
        <name>remrem</name>
        <email>vcxwv@sdsfg.com</email>
        <datetime>2014-09-23 07:41:57</datetime>
        <lang>fr</lang>
    </userdetails>
</DS>
```

There are only five special characters in XML:  `&lt;` (<), `&amp;` (&), `&gt;` (>), `&quot;` ("), and `&apos;` ('). However, tag names have more restrictions. A tag name is a token beginning with a letter or one of a few punctuation characters, and continuing with letters, digits, hyphens, underscores, colons, or full stops, together known as name characters. Or more precise:

```
NameChar ::= Letter | Digit | '.' | '-' | '_' | ':' | CombiningChar | Extender
Name ::= (Letter | '_' | ':') (NameChar)*
```

It can get quite complicated, but for simplicity just stick to what you know from HTML and almost any programming language using variable names.

**Use tags only to identify the type of content they hold.**

Comment: can I have multiple <userdetails> ?

Comment: @RemRem yes you can have